# How can I move my django app's large production postgres database table data to development database?

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I have a Production database table called sensordata with over 70 million entries, I need to have the same in my development database so I can check speed tests and do some query optimization. I used django 1.11 and postgres. All the other tables in development have data exactly same as in production except for sensordata. I tried doing dumpdata and loaddata but the json file obtained after dumpdata was too large to do loaddata. Is there anyway to do this with postgres?

Comment: What is `dumpdata`? Did you try dumping to an archive with [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html)? You can then restore using [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: dumpdata is django's command line utility Outputs to standard output all data in the database table specified in a specified format , in this case i tried json

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata

Comment: OK, thanks for the reference. Use `pg_dump`, it will create a more compact file. Alternatively, break your existing JSON file into smaller chunks and load each individually.

Comment: i got a db.sql file after doing -->  pg_dump -t '"Webapp_sensordata"' roctim > db.sql . HOw do i pg_restore just the table back into my development database table also called Webapp_sensordata in database roctim?